# How to handle events simpler in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

As a beginner with javascript, I am following [this tutorial](http://matt.might.net/articles/learning-javascript-in-small-bites-part-2/) . At the top of that page simple forms and the use of an event handler is explained,  while at the bottom of the page an exercise to create a simple calculator is given [calculator.html](http://matt.might.net/articles/learning-javascript-in-small-bites-part-2/calculator.html).

I have come up with a very cumbersome solution to handle events when a number or operation is pressed. Here is what I have implemented:

```
function pressingNumber(number) {
    document.getElementById("calc-output").innerHTML = number;
}

function press1() {pressingNumber(1);}
function press2() {pressingNumber(2);}
function press3() {pressingNumber(3);}
var button1 = document.getElementById("button-1");
var button2 = document.getElementById("button-2");
var button3 = document.getElementById("button-3");
button1.onclick = press1;    
button2.onclick = press2;
button3.onclick = press3;
```

Is this the way to go? Is there a simpler way? I tried the following syntax which does not seem to work:

```
function pressingNumber(number) {
    document.getElementById("calc-output").innerHTML = number;
}

var button1 = document.getElementById("button-1");
var button2 = document.getElementById("button-2");
var button3 = document.getElementById("button-3");
button1.onclick = pressingNumber(1);    
button2.onclick = pressingNumber(2);
button3.onclick = pressingNumber(3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, this is your shortest method

```
<input type="button" value="1" onclick="pressNumber(1)">
<input type="button" value="2" onclick="pressNumber(2)">

function pressNumber(number) {
    document.getElementById("calc-output").innerHTML = number;
}
```

The problem in your original code was that you are calling a function with `()`in a place where you have to assign a function.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this line of code:

```
button1 = document.getElementById("button-1");
```

What does it do? It calls the function `document.getElementById` and assigns its return value to `button1`.

Now look at this line of code:

```
button1.onclick = pressingNumber(1);
```

What does this do? It **calls the function** `pressingNumber` and **assigns its return value** to `button1.onclick`.

So what does `pressingNumber(1)` return? Well, nothing, since `pressingNumber` has no `return` statement.

So you're assigning **nothing** to `button1.onclick`, and then wondering... why is it doing nothing? ;)

One of the things you'll learn is that if you just read your code aloud, explaining what it does step by step, you'll quickly solve your own problems. I have a rubber duck on my desk that I explain things to, and most of the time that's all I need to solve a problem.

In this case, you want to stick with the original code. It **assigns the function itself**, it doesn't call it. It is only called when `onclick` triggers.

Comment: he can directly pass value from html like function(value),instead of writing separate functions,am i right?

Answer (score 1):

Note that onclick events always come with a link to the div that triggered the event. You should make use of that to capture which button was clicked. e in below function will refer to the clickevent. e.target will refer to the div, e.target.id will refer to the id of said div.

```
function buttonClicked(e){
    console.log(e.target.id);
    console.log('clicked in',document.getElementById(e.target.id).parentNode.id);
}
```

You could then attach said function to your div like so.

```
document.getElementById(buttonDivName).addEventListener("click", buttonClicked)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
button1.addEventListener("click", pressingNumber(1));
button2.addEventListener("click", pressingNumber(2));
button3.addEventListener("click", pressingNumber(3));
```